# jquery - Aminate just the element clicked and hide another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a menu. When a menu element is clicked I want to animate the width of its border-bottom. 
My problem here is that I cannot find the way how to bring the border-bottom width to '0' when another element is clicked.

Any solution?

```js
$("#hww, #proj, #digi, #cont").click(function(){
 
 $( this ).animate({
   
   borderBottomWidth: "10px",
   }, 200 );
   
   
});
```

```css
.menu_text {
 
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: 20px;

 margin-right: 100px;
 
 padding-left: 0px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 0px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu_bar">
  <div id="menu_box">
  <div id="cont" class="menu_text">CONTACT</div>
  <div id="digi" class="menu_text">DIGITAL SERVICES</div>
 
 <div id="proj" class="menu_text">PROJECTS</div>
 <div id="hww" class="menu_text">HOW WE WORK</div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a reference to all elements in a variable and animate them to 0.

```js
var menu = $("#hww, #proj, #digi, #cont").click(function() {
  
  // remove from previous element
  menu.not(this).animate({
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  }, 200);

  // show on current
  $(this).animate({
    borderBottomWidth: "10px",
  }, 200);


});
```

```css
.menu_text {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu_bar">
  <div id="menu_box">
    <div id="cont" class="menu_text">CONTACT</div>
    <div id="digi" class="menu_text">DIGITAL SERVICES</div>

    <div id="proj" class="menu_text">PROJECTS</div>
    <div id="hww" class="menu_text">HOW WE WORK</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

A better solution, though, would be to handle everything through CSS

```js
$("#menu_box").on('click', '.menu_text', function(e){
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.menu_text {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  
  transition: border-bottom-width 200ms;
}

.menu_text.active{
  border-bottom-width:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu_bar">
  <div id="menu_box">
    <div id="cont" class="menu_text">CONTACT</div>
    <div id="digi" class="menu_text">DIGITAL SERVICES</div>

    <div id="proj" class="menu_text">PROJECTS</div>
    <div id="hww" class="menu_text">HOW WE WORK</div>

  </div>
</div>
```